# JAX: count unique elements in array

Tags: jit, jax

I have a jitted function where one of the inputs is an array whose number of unique elements I would like to calculate. I cannot use jax.numpy.unique, it throws a ConcretizationTypeError due to the output of unique being of variable size. Any algorithmic workarounds_

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to sort the array and count the number of adjacent entries which are not equal. For example:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

x = jnp.array([3, 2, 1, 2, 3])

@jax.jit
def count_unique(x):
  x = jnp.sort(x)
  return 1 + (x[1:] != x[:-1]).sum()

print(count_unique(x))
# 3
```